# How to Position a Div in a specific area?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I am trying to create a similar layout to one used by twitter as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

The Part I am trying to do is where the profile picture is. I am trying to add a div that is positioned over another div and I really have no idea where to start.

I have the nav and the blue container but not sure how to create the div on top like shown.

http://www.bootply.com/v7fKXw63nh

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please post some code so we can help you find a solution, not do it for you.

Comment: This is what I have tried, just wasnt sure if it was the correct way to do it hence the question on approaches. http://www.bootply.com/kFu3GwhKqF

Answer (score 1):

Try using the relative or absolute CSS positions.

For example, put the following code at the bottom of your example.

```
<div style="position: absolute; 
            left: 150px; 
            top: 120px; 
            width: 75px; 
            height: 75px; 
            background-color: #666"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#profileWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}
#topHeader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#profiler {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.fa {
  color: lightgray;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.fa:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="profileWrapper">
  <div id="topHeader">
    <div id="profiler"><span class="fa fa-camera fa-3x"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fiddle link

 (Don't forget to resize the demo section in fiddle)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS(used in the demo):

```
.col-sm-12{
  height:100px;
  background:#33CCFF ;
}
.col-sm-2{
  height:150px;
  background:#33CCFF;
  margin-top:50px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```